# Malformed Reset password URL, React App broken

Tags: reactjs, webpack, hash, uri, reset-password

I Have URL like this:
`http://localhost:3030/reset/8d17c00a6b13d101df8d42fbfeade07917a08d867c36a5648875110e69fc80448d3c42d0289f6f83922e4f6dee3ff832/5a9245e39941ed5bad45c95998a8bfd8`

This URL contains hashed data of user needed lately to authenticate in the reset password process. Unfortunately, this link is the only one that does not work. The page won't start and there is an error stating that the main.js file could not be loaded.

[image]

The second thing: Favicon also throws an error that Icon cannot be loaded. URIError is a hint here for me that maybe the link is wrong. And webpack can't parse it. But I don't know what or how to fix it

`URIError: Failed to decode param '/reset/8d17c00a6b13d101df8d42fbfeade07917a08d867c36a5648875110e69fc80448d3c42d0289f6f83922e4f6dee3ff832/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico'`

Answer (score 0):

This solution helps me: [configure webpack to use absolute path instead of relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147275/configure-webpack-to-use-absolute-path-instead-of-relative-path)

`output: { filename: './public/javascript/[name].js', publicPath: '/', }`